# How to stub Puppet::Type('user).instances.select

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

In a fact Im calling

```
Puppet::Type('user').instances.select do |user|
#do something with user
end
```

How can I stub that in a spec test? I have something like:

```
Puppet::Type.type(:user).stubs(:instances).returns(
    'User[root]','User[bin]'])
```

but that stubs it with an array and not a User object. How can I stub it correctly?

Comment: You should be mocking instead. Take a look at this and see if it helps: https://github.com/Accuity/rspec-puppet-utils#mockresource-experimental-feature

Comment: Try making it return an array of users, such as `.returns([user1, user])` (you have to define the users variables first)

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks. I made it work with your suggestion. The solution looks like: `user1=Puppet::Type::type(:user).new( name: 'root', ensure: 'present')  Puppet::Type.type(:user).stubs(:instances).returns([user1])`

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for the link, it is something I will look into for other spec test.

Comment: @user1571135 cool, feel free to post your own answer and accept it in 2 days time so that the question won't show up as open.

Comment: @user1571135 I actually misunderstood your question and was looking for something way more complicated than it actually was. The root problem here is that `'User[root]'` is a string and the method `Puppet::Type.instances` returns resource objects in the catalog. I am not sure how you went in that direction, otherwise I would point at some helpful documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to ensure that the return value was a user object. I did that by:

```
user1=Puppet::Type::type(:user).new( name: 'root', ensure: 'present') 
Puppet::Type.type(:user).stubs(:instances).returns([user1])
```